# Square subplots of same size without equal axis ratio or shared axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have multiple subplots with different axis scales showing different stuff. One of them has an equal axis ratio but the others don't (and I don't want them to have an equal axis ratio). I just want to them all to be square and of even size. This is a minimal example showing my problem:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=3)
fig.set_size_inches(7,3)
ax[0].plot([0,1],[0,1])
ax[1].plot([0,1,2],[0,3,1])
ax[2].plot([0,1,2],[0,4,1])
ax[0].set_aspect("equal")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Try set_box_aspect

Comment: try this: `plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=3,subplot_kw=dict(box_aspect=1))`